# "data-type" argument in link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ujs, link-to-remote

Is there any shortcut for:

```
link_to 'title', path, 'data-type' => :html
```

I thought `:type=>:html` would work, much as `:remote=>true` transforms to `data-remote='true'`, but not supported.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes:

```
link_to 'title', path, data: { type: :html }
```

*small edit*

It comes from the tag helper: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag

Its maybe not a shortcut in your case but can be very handy if you have to set multiple data-attributes:

```
link_to 'title', path, data: { first_name: @user.first_name, 
                               last_name:  @user.last_name,
                               # etc. }
```

But no, no `type: :html`, sorry...

Comment: Thanks, I'll use a helper method for now to default this setting along with remote: https://gist.github.com/1513760.